# c#: provide ghostscript dll to imagemagick

Tags: c#, imagemagick, ghostscript

what im trying to do here is convert the .eps file to jpg

im using ImageMagick but the problem with this is i need to install Ghostscript.

is there a way to just provide the ghostscript dll to the imagemagick. so that the i dont need to install Ghostscript to the computer that are going to use my program?

this is my code

```
using (MagickImage image = new MagickImage("myeps.eps"))
{
  image.Write("mjpgoutput.jpg");
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Your question was already answered in the documentation of Magick.NET (https://github.com/dlemstra/Magick.NET/blob/main/docs/Readme.md)

> If you don't want to install Ghostscript on your machine you can copy
> gsdll32.dll/gsdl64.dll and gswin32c.exe/gswin64c.exe to your server
> and tell Magick.NET where the file is located with the code below.

```
MagickNET.SetGhostscriptDirectory(@"C:\MyProgram\Ghostscript");
```

*Be aware that you need a license if you want to use Ghostscript commercially.*